# Laravel Blade : What does it mean the double column in parameter in @extends('adminlte::page')

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to use this Admin Panel : https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE

But i don't understand this syntax : `@extends('adminlte::page')`.
 The page is a view but what does it mean to add adminlte and the double column in this example ?

I have never seen this syntax, and i didn't find about it in the Laravel blade docs, can anyone enlighten me please ?

Comment: I take you probably overlooked it on laravel's documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#extending-a-layout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is used to identify the package from which the view should be loaded from. For example you have a package named `neokyuubi/courier` inside your vendor folder, and you want to load views from there into the application. Then you would use `courier::index` to identify your view. if you use `@import('index')` the framework will look into `resources\views\index.blade.php` but when you write your package before the view name, it'll look first to `resources\views\vendor\courier\index.blade.php` and when it doesn't find the view, it'll look for your package views directory.

But, you need to register your views like this first inside your package's service provider:

```
$this->loadViewsFrom("path\to\your\view\folder", "courier");
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/packages#views

Comment: Thank you so much, i was thinking that i need to copy all the content of AdminLTE package in to my public folder, specially since this package does not have a command to publish its assets and pages.

Comment: @Neokyuubi you're welcome. You can accept the answer if you think it's the correct answer.