# What does laravel blade component path syntax mean?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

After adding some simple notification into my project i have some files added in 'resources/views/' path. These files are layouts for email message. Some of them contain code of using blade component directive, that i can't undestand. For example:

```
    @component('mail::layout')
    ...
       some code
    ...
    @endcomponent
```

So my question is

What does "::" syntax mean in laravel blade component directive?

I assume it must be some kind of "path". But i can't find any documentation about it.

Comment: I believe you are looking for the same answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53189652/laravel-blade-what-does-it-mean-the-double-column-in-parameter-in-extendsad

Comment: Thank you for help. This is what I need.

Comment: Your Welcome, Keep Coding :)